# Set ItemsPanel of a DataGridCellsPresenter via Style not working

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, itemspanel

I'm trying to set the `ItemsPanel` of a `DataGridCellsPresenter` in the Resources of my Window.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCellsPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WPFVarTab:CustomDataGridCellsPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But my `CustomDataGridCellsPanel` is not used. It still uses the `DataGridCellsPanel`.

What am I doing wrong?